# Splitting a string and wihtout loosing the separator

Tags: python

I have a string `ADFBDFDS`. I want to split the string in two ways: Either like this `ADFB|DFDS` or this `ADF|BDFDS`. Is there a method where I can use `B` as a regex and use an additional argument whether I want it so split the string in after`B` or before `B`? Thanks!

Comment: maybe add b after the fact to the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index20) and [Lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index22) for that:

```
import re

data = "ADFBDFDS"

split_after = re.split('(?<=B)', data)  # ['ADFB', 'DFDS']
split_before = re.split('(?=B)', data)  # ['ADF', 'BDFDS']
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much, is there also a way i can do this?                                   ```split_after = re.split('(?<=B|?<=A)', data)  # ['A','DFB', 'DFDS']```

Comment: Almost, Lookarounds must be enclosed like that: ``(?<=B)|(?<=A)``

Comment: You can also do it like that ``(?<=[BA])`` or like that ``(?<=B|A)``.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
string = "ADFBDFDS"
string = string.replace("B"," B ")
before_b = string.split(" ")[0] #ADF
after_b = string.split(" ")[2]  #DFDS
```

with split